# Django 1.4 in windows 7 "No FlatPage matches the given query"

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

I already searched for everything I could, but this annoying error is still there. The admin interface (localhost:8000/admin/) works fine, but no one else. Obs.: Im using Apress - Practical Django Projects (2nd edition) to learn Django. I'll post my code here so somebody can tell what I did wrong. Thanks!
Code:

**settings.py**

```
    # Django settings for cms project.
    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
    APPEND_SLASH = True
    ADMINS = (
        # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
    )

    MANAGERS = ADMINS

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
                    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql',                 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'C:\Users\Vinicius\Desktop\Work\Djangoprojects\cms\cms.db',                              # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }

    # Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
    # although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
    # On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
    # timezone as the operating system.
    # If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
    # system time zone.
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

    # Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
    # http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    SITE_ID = 1

    # If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
    # to load the internationalization machinery.
    USE_I18N = True

    # If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
    # calendars according to the current locale.
    USE_L10N = True

    # If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
    USE_TZ = True

    # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = ''

    # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
    # trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
    MEDIA_URL = ''

    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = ''

    # URL prefix for static files.
    # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Additional locations of static files
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    )

    # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
    # various locations.
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    )

    # Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
    SECRET_KEY = 'notgiven'

    # List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )


    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
        # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
        # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'cms.urls'

    # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cms.wsgi.application'

    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        'C:/Users/Vinicius/Desktop/Work/Djangoprojects/cms/templates/'
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.flatpages',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        # 'django.contrib.admin',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
        # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    )

    # A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
    # performed by this configuration is to send an email to
    # the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
    # more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
    LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
            },
        }
    }
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

    # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
    )
```

PS: Everything is idented correctly. So if there are some identation mistakes, it's because I did the copy/paste real quick.

Comment: maybe this helps? http://benhealey.info/2009/07/07/getting-a-no-flatpage-matches-the-given-query-error/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not include flatpages in your url conf.

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')), # remove this
```

That's probably why you're getting the error... as flatpages practically match any URL.

Normally flatpages work via the flatpage fallback middleware that will attempt to locate a flatpage IF no other urls match.

Comment: Ok, i removed the `url(r'',include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),` but the program is still not finding the default.html template by itself. How do I do that(sry I'm new at Django)?

Comment: So, what is the templates folder for? And where django stores this templates that I made in the flatpages admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of problem is not putting the correct `SITE_ID` number in `settings.py`

You can find the correct site id for `127.0.0.1:8000` (assuming you use the default port) by inspecting the table `django_flatpage_sites` in your database. The site id will be found in the column `site_id`.

Updating the `SITE_ID` to that number in `settings.py` , solved the issue for me.